# Roll down the window

Tags: grammar

> "Roll down the window"
>
> "Pull down the window"

What word to be used for turn the window up or down as the car windows are controlled by switches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic expression is still "roll down" even though most cars use buttons or switches instead of handles.

> Could you please **roll down the window** so we can get some fresh air?